# How to insert a directory in mySQL String from java using "\"?

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to insert an address from Java to a mySQL database in a String. The problem is that I ask for the address to the user and he gives me something like this: "C:\Users\Me\Desktop" so when I pass this string to mySQL it doesn't recognise this as it should be, it deletes the "\".
I have being trying to use .replaceAll("\", "\\"); but it doesn't work at all.

What's the best solutions?

Thank you!

Code:

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        FilaPanel fila = main.getFila((JButton) e.getSource());
        String param = "";
        String dir = fila.getDirMod();
        // TODO
        // dir.replaceAll("\\\\\\", "/");

        main.getGestionDatos().insertaModulo(fila.getNomMod(), dir, param,main.getConexion());
        main.añadeFilaModulos();
    }

public void insertaModulo(String nombre, String directorio, String param, Connection conexion) {
    try {
        Statement s = conexion.createStatement();
        s.executeUpdate("insert into modulo (nombre, directorio, parámetros) values ('" + nombre + "','"
                + directorio + "','" + param + "');");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: please show us the regarding code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `PreparedStatement`:

```
String lSql = "insert into modulo (nombre, directorio, parámetros) values (?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement s = conexion.createPrepareStatement(lSql);
s.setString(1,"Test1");
s.setString(2,"c:\backslashes\p");
s.setString(3,"Test3");
s.executeUpdate();
```

I dont know the datatypes of nombre and parámetros. Could be that you have to use `setInt` instead of `setString`.